# Using command ssh -X in script file executes only ssh command

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Can't execute any command after the server changes to s00246 using the below given ssh command is executed.

```
ssh -X amsdc2-n-s00246
```

I want to execute this commands given below:

```
case $user in
    246)
        xauth list | grep amsdc2-n-s00246 > tempfile.txt
        last_line=$(tail -1 tempfile.txt)
        ;;
    247)
        $(xauth list | grep amsdc2-n-s00247) >tempfile.txt
        last_line=$(tail -1 tempfile.txt)
        ;;
    248)
        $(xauth list | grep amsdc2-n-s00248) >tempfile.txt
        last_line=$(tail -1 tempfile.txt)
        ;;
    249)
        $(xauth list | grep amsdc2-n-s00249) >tempfile.txt
        last_line=$(tail -1 tempfile.txt)
        ;;
    250)
        $(xauth list | grep amsdc2-n-s00250) >tempfile.txt
        last_line=$(tail -1 tempfile.txt)
        ;;
esac
```

Plus I am also not able to copy the output of xauth command into tempfile.txt